# selenium2library,how to get id from an attribute if it's not a web element?

Tags: xpath, robotframework, selenium2library

I'm trying to get element id (here a list) from an element attribute with no success.Here is my html code:

I tried:

```
 get element attribute //*[@class="rqbar"]@id
```

Is there a way to get the Id?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, this list is not visible on the webpage, it is just the begining of the HTML which describes the page and its elements. it is <ul  blablabla>  and  my goal is (was) to get all the text of this page and compare it with a fixes static text to see if something is missing as we do with Drop-down menu items on a page.

Comment: if it's not inside the `<body>` tag, I don't think selenium can access it. Selenium can only work with what is visible on the page.

Comment: of course it's inside the <body>

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost correct. Here are my corrections:

```
*** Settings ***
Library                 Selenium2Library
Suite Teardown          Close All Browsers

*** Test Cases ***
StackOverflow
    Open Browser     http://www.google.com/    Chrome
    ${id}=           get element attribute     xpath=//*[@class="sbib_b"]@id
```

Comment: I tried yours and it works out. I think my problem is related to the definition of a web element.   because in the same page you have mentioned above, i try to get the id of another "element" which is  csi, but it fails because it says that it doesn't find this element. even though it exists inside the html    ${test}    Get Element Attribute    //*[@name="csi"]@id

Comment: Did you have "xpath=" prefix before xpath? IIRC it is very important. Does this work:  Get Element Attribute xpath=//*[@name="csi"]@id?

Comment: yes, i did have.  I can't try it again because on google.com the textarea doesn't have the name attribute any more at this time.

Comment: Google id and class names change regularly. I think it is by design. Right-click textbox and select inspect to see it's' attributes and new class name.